# postgresql how to draft not in statement with join table

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 postgresql tables : Documents, Keywords and a join table.

I have query that searches document.id and document.date if certain keywords are related to that document. That works fine like so:

```
SELECT 
    documents.id, documents.document_date
FROM
    documents
        INNER JOIN
    documents_keywords ON documents_keywords.document_id = documents.id
        INNER JOIN
    keywords ON keywords.id = documents_keywords.keyword_id
WHERE
    keywords.keyword IN ('bread' , 'cake')
GROUP BY documents.id
```

This returns:

```
 id | document_date 
----+-----------
  4 |      1200
 12 |      1280
(2 rows)
```

I also want to exclude keywords. I thought I could do `NOT IN` like so:

```
SELECT 
    documents.id, documents.document_date
FROM
    documents
        INNER JOIN
    documents_keywords ON documents_keywords.document_id = documents.id
        INNER JOIN
    keywords ON keywords.id = documents_keywords.keyword_id
WHERE
    keywords.keyword NOT IN ('cranberries')
GROUP BY documents.id
```

But that always returns empty, whatever keyword I put:

```
 id | document_date 
----+-----------
(0 rows)
```

This is incorrect. I expected:

```
 id | document_date 
----+-----------
  4 |      1200
(1 row)
```

Comment: Look OK. Please post the data on which the first one works and second one doesn't. and what would the expected output look like?

Comment: I have update the question. I put `bread` , `cake` and `cranberries` , which are not the words I use. The keywords are all latin words.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an array expression, like this:

```
 WHERE keyword = any(array['bread', 'cake'])
```

when you want to include a row.

If you want to exclude something, you have to do the NOT IN over a subselect of the inverse condition, e.g.

```
SELECT ... WHERE document_id NOT IN
(SELECT document_id FROM ...joins... WHERE keyword = ANY(array['cranberry']))
```

Here is an example I put together:

```
WITH documents(d_id, date) AS (
VALUES(1,'1000'),(2,'2000'),(3,'3000'),(4,'4000')
),

keywords(k_id, keyword) AS (
VALUES(1, 'cake'), (2, 'bread'), (3, 'cranberry')
),
documents_keywords (d_id, k_id) AS (
VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3)
)
SELECT * FROM documents where d_id NOT IN (
  SELECT d_id FROM 
  documents 
  JOIN documents_keywords USING(d_id) 
  JOIN keywords USING(k_id)
  WHERE keyword = ANY(array['cranberry'])
)
```

Also, I am not sure why you are using `GROUP BY`, I don't think you need it.

Comment: Removing the `GROUP BY` provokes an error = `ERROR:  column "actes.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: The second proposal `WHERE keyword <> all(array['cranberries'])` continues to return also the documents that do have 'cranberries' among their keywords. For example, I have a document.id="2" and the document.date="1200". The keywords that are associated are `'table','chair',kitchen oven','cranberries','spoon'` . I need to return the document that don't have 'cranberries' among the associated keywords. However, this still returns document 2.